# how to add object to json element in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am newbee to ruby and rails.I have a json structure. while respond to controller i have to add new json element with a object, which i trying to add by below code:-

```
arr1 = @providers
arr1.each { |x| 
            puts x.id 
            @catalog = ProviderCatalogDetail.select("name","code").where(provider_id: x.id)
            #puts x.pluck(:name)
            #byebug
            
            obj = {"id":1,"name":"test"} ## Test value
            x['catalog_name'] = JSON.generate(obj) # I have tried multiple thing here but nothing works here
            @catalog.to_json
          }

resp = arr1.to_json
render plain: resp,content_type: 'application/json'
```

In response ,I get from controller as:

```
"catalog_name":"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test\"}]"
```

No matter what i try integer or any other way , the `catalog_name` is always set as string `""`. I have another json array which i have to as object.

I have to set object. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Expected output is below:

```
{
    "id": 44,
    "building_name": "SLV13",
    "address": "Hadosiddapur",
    "description": "goodupdated12",
    "alias": "bajarangiupdated13",
    "mobile_number": "80901173612",
    "email_address": "samash1212@gmail.com",
    "provider_profiles_id": 50,
    "catalog_name": [{"id":1,"name":"test"}]
}
```

Comment: Your expected result?  Guess you don't need that `JSON#generate`, just write `x['catalog_name'] = [1]`.

Comment: What does `@providers` return? An JSON, Hash, or a list of Active Record objects? What is the expected output?

Comment: Edited the question to depict the expected output

Comment: @halfelf, I have tried it does not work still , i see "catalog_name":"[1]" in response